# How to pass parameter to Ajax update expression

Tags: primefaces, el

I want to pass the value from `"processContext.targetUpdate"` from managed bean to `'update'` tag in `commandButton`, if it is not `null`.

So I did:

```
<p:commandButton
                                update="@(.painelInfoDer) 
                                @(.msgsDialogAltDer) 
                                @(.opValorAtualDer) 
                                @(.outputPanel) 
                                @(.#{processContext.targetUpdate != null?processContext.targetUpdate:@none})"
```

But I received an error:

```
Caused by: com.sun.el.parser.ParseException: Encountered "@" at line 1, column 157.
Was expecting one of:
    <INTEGER_LITERAL> ...
    <FLOATING_POINT_LITERAL> ...
    <STRING_LITERAL> ...
    "true" ...
    "false" ...
    "null" ...
    "(" ...
    "!" ...
    "not" ...
    "empty" ...
    "-" ...
    <IDENTIFIER> ...
```

What's wrong with this expression? Will pass parameter like this work as I expect?

I think the problems is the @none, now I change to:

```
<p:commandButton
                                update="@(.painelInfoDer) 
                                @(.msgsDialogAltDer) 
                                @(.opValorAtualDer) 
                                @(.outputPanel) 
                                @(.#{processContext.targetUpdate != null?processContext.targetUpdate:''})"
```

and now the button disappear.

Comment: I don't solve yet, after I changed it as i said in edit it the button is not showing anymore

Comment: Any javascript errors? Any server side errors?

Comment: And when do you expect this expression to be populated? It is **not** updated during the ajax request...